# Populate select2 field with multiple true option on page load in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-select2

I have a rails application where i am trying to add a ruby select tag with jquery select2, the select 2 works perfectly fine. But i want if the user re-vist that page it should show them the value which they previously selected.

This is my code

view.html.erb file

```
<% if @select2_values.present? %>
   <%= select_tag "select2_name", options_for_select(@select2_values.map { |obj| [obj[:text], obj[:id]] }), multiple: true, class: "form-control select2", id: "resultOf_select2" %>
<% else %>
   <%= select_tag "select2_name", options_for_select([]), multiple: true, class: "form-control select2", id: "resultOf_select2" %>
 <% end %>
```

When i put `binding.pry` inside the if statement it properly stops there, and also when i check the console the `@select2_values` array looks like this

```
[{ :id 1, :text "some text" },
 { :id 2, :text "some text" },
 { :id 3, :text "some text" },
]
```

If i remove the `multiple : true` option it properly display's the first value of the  `@select2_values` array. Can some one help me figure out how can i show all the values with `multiple:true` option

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First: you need to store user selected values somewhere... for example localstorage(because if you use sessionStorage this values will be lost)

Second: when user visits your page try to get this user selected values... if there is something then set this values to select2 like this:

$('#mySelect2').val(['1', '2']);

you can found more information about localstorage here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_storage.asp

hope it helps

Comment: I have store the data in the database so i do the first step ,
then when the user visits my page again i get the selected values in a ruby variable which is `@select2_values` which is the second step,
then i try assigning the value the way you showed in third step by both ways directly using my ruby variable or creating a javascript variable and assigning my ruby variable value to it and then setting the value but in both ways it doesnt work

Comment: Then inside a foreach you can verify if a value is selected... if value is selected then push it to an array and finally set this value on select2... somethin like this:

var selectedValues = new Array();
options_for_select.forEach(opt => {
    select2_values.forEach(selectedOpt => {
      if(opt.id == selectedOpt.id){
        selectedValues.push(element.text);
      }
    }); 
  });
$('#mySelect2').val(selectedValues);